# How to force Set the number of printed pages (2 in this case) of a range

Tags: vba, excel

How do I force a range in Excel VBA say ("a1:z60") to print ONLY two pages page(1) from ("a1:z40") and page(2) from ("a41:z60").

Also separately, how can I force the same range say ("a1:z60") to print ONLY two pages page(1) from ("a1:p60") and page(2) from ("q1:z60").

In addition I want the zoom to be maximum possible (under the given conditions) for each of my two pages.

Many Thanks

Comment: By inserting a pagebreak at row 41?

Comment: I am new to vba ... can you please elaborate

Comment: Do this. Record a macro and then insert a pagebreak. see what code do you get :)

Comment: How will the pagebreak at row 41 stop the subsequent pages being printed. (ie. say we get page(1) till a40, but there after there could be 15 other pages between (a41 and a60) .... how do we stop that ...

Comment: 1st page break at 40. 2nd at 60. none in between :)

Comment: Which Excel version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To print a selection on a page:

```
Range("A1:E44").Select
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With
Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1
```

change range to whatever range you need, and change the pages wide & tall to how you want the page to be seen